# how to use CSS opacity to let background bleed through in IE8?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page with a pink background image.  I want to define a DIV on the page for text, but I want the background to show in the DIV much paler, almost white.  I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work on IE8.

My HTML...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
<body>

<div class="div1">
testing
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and here's my CSS file ...

```
body
{
background-image:url('back.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat;
} 

.div1
{
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
background: #ffffff;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @sinsedrix The problem is the div background is solid white on IE8. (Works in Firefox where the background image bleeds through.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you have to keep in mind is that the opacity property will affect the opacity of the *entire* element, including its text/children. If you want to affect JUST the background, you will need to approach it in a different way.

You could use RGBA for modern browsers:

```
.div1 {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .4);
}
```

Then, in a separate IE stylesheet (using conditional comments or similar method):

```
.div1 {
  background: transparent url(white_trans.png);
 }
```

You would need to make a PNG-24 image, 1px x 1px, that was just simply white reduced to 40% opacity. That will work in IE7 & 8.

Comment: No need to use a separate IE-only stylesheet. You can use normal [progressive enhancement](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/#fallback-color).

Comment: True, you don't, but as most projects I'm working on tend to need other fixes in IE, I usually have a separate IE stylesheet anyway. It's just how I roll. Another good option is to use [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com) and target the .no-rgba class.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `zoom: 1` declaration to your `.div1` block.

Comment: What does this do?  I added it, saw no change.

Comment: @RobertHume IE8 by default does support the `opacity` property, but based on your HTML I see that you don't have a DOCTYPE specified, and hence IE renders your page in quirks mode. This solution should fix the opacity for quirks mode, as well as older IEs. It does get fixed based on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w2wL7/.

Comment: I see it working there in jsfiddle -- but I can't get it to work locally -- I added to my html page: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> and I added zoom: 1; to the css -- what am I missing?

Comment: @RobertHume Just some explanations. As I mentioned, IE8 does support the `opacity` property if there is a doctype, but you have specified the latter incorrectly - you should only have the `<!DOCTYPE ...>` line at the very top of your HTML file, don't add the `<?xml .../>` line. This should solve your issue without `zoom: 1;` for IE8. If your local files are on a network however, IE8 still tends to open them in quirks mode, which is irritating if you are trying to see how they look. `zoom: 1;` should fix the issue for this case, as well as for older IEs - are you sure you added it correctly?

Comment: Removed the <?xml .../> -- weird that it still doesn't work.  The files are on a folder on my local machine.  Oh well, this is taking too much time, thanks IE, I'll just have to make a separate image for the div background.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a plain (solid) color as background, then, I would suggest you to just use a paler pink for your DIV.

This will create the illusion of opacity. And more importantly, you will not face issues with some browsers.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is the main background has a nice polka dot pattern on it that I'd like to see throughout.  If I use a paler version with the dots for the DIV then the dots won't line up, so if I take your suggestion I have to emotionally accept that I lose my dots. :)